# How to set a page as homepage in stead of the newspages?

Tags: theme-development, themes, permalinks

I need some help.
I want the same as on this site: http://www.123ipad.nl/ (this is my website)
When you go to the home url you come to a page in stead of the newspage.
The newspages are in the submap [/ipad](http://www.123ipad.nl/ipad)

**So i have two questions:**

1: how do i get the newspages in the submap [/ipad](http://www.123ipad.nl/ipad)

2: How do i set my first created page permalink as homepage? Same as on this image:

> [image]

where you see nothing after `http://www.123ipad.nl/` )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

please make yourself comfortable with the settings WordPress has to offer regarding your Homepage or Startpage as some call it.

Those are *not* configured via that *permalink setting* of a specific page (as your image shows) but with options on the [Settings Reading SubPanel (Wordpress Codex)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Reading_SubPanel).

Probably [Creating a Static Front Page (Wordpress Codex)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page) is exactly what you're looking for.

This might not answer all your questions but might be helpful for a start.

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what i was looking for! I didn't see those settings because i deleted all newsposts and pages so the settings where not available :-)